# Finding power series and ROC of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have the function $f(z) = \frac{3iz-6i}{z-3}$

I need to find a power series $\sum c_n (z-1)^n$ about $z_0 = 1$

I can rewrite $f$ as $\frac{2i-iz}{1-\frac{z}{3}}$, where I'm guessing the ROC would then be $3$.

However I have it in the form $\frac{a}{1-r}$ and I'm not sure with $a$ being dependent on $z$ that I can get a correct power series, also I don't see how we get his power series about $1$.

I've considered Taylor Series, but it seems far too complicated with complex numbers.

I've tried writing it as $3i \frac{z-2}{z-3}$ where now I just need to get the power series for $\frac{z-2}{z-3}$ but still having trouble.

Any ideas what a general approach might be.  I'm more interested in the method over the answer.

EDIT:

I've also tried writing it as

$3i(\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{z}})+2i (\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{3}})$

which would get me ROC = $3$ again. But I'm not sure how this would be about $z_0 = 1$

Comment: You want a power series with centre $1$. Writing $z = w+1$ may help finding it.

Comment: Can you explain a little further. Sorry if I'm a bit confused

Comment: $w$ is $z-1$. So you want an expansion in terms of $w$. If you had for example $\frac{1}{z-5}$ and wanted to expand it as a power series in $z-2$, you'd set $z = w+2$, and in terms of $w$ the function becomes $\frac{1}{(w+2)-5} = \frac{1}{w-3} = -\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{1-w/3}$. You know how to expand that into a geometric series (with common ratio $w/3$), and then you just replace $w$ with $z-2$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. From this I get $3i(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{w}})-\frac{3i}{2}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{w}{2}})+3i(\frac{1}{1-\frac{w}{2}})$. However I'm not sure how to get the ROC for $\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{w}}$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(z)=\frac{3iz-6i}{z-3}$ has a simple pole at $z=3$. We want to develop $f$ into a power series at $z_0=1$. Since the ROC is the distance from the center of the series to the nearest *[singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28mathematics%29)* or *[branch point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point)* we obtain $ROC=2$.

> The idea is to transform the function to use a *[geometric series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* with center $z=z_0$.
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{z-a}&=-\frac{1}{(a-z_0)-(z-z_0)}\\
> &=-\frac{1}{a-z_0}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-z_0}{a-z_0}}\\
> &=-\frac{1}{a-z_0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a-z_0)^n}(z-z_0)^n\qquad\qquad|z-z_0|<|a-z_0|
> \end{align*}

In the following the first steps of the calculation:

> We obtain for $|z-1|<2$
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)&=\frac{3iz-6i}{z-3}\\
> &=-\frac{3iz-6i}{2-(z-1)}\\
> &=-\frac{3iz-6i}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-1}{2}}\\
> &=3i\frac{1-(z-1)}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}(z-1)^n\\
> &=\cdots
> \end{align*}